# Understanding a derivation of Lorentz Transformation

Tags: special-relativity

I was reading: (pdf can be downloaded)
Derivation of the Lorentz Transformation
Lecture Note for PHYS 171H, 270, 374, 411, 601
by Victor M. Yakovenko:

*S`* is moving with velocity *v* wrt *S*

Starts with assumption:

2) $x` = Ax + Bt$

3) $t` = Cx + Dt$

The origin of *O'* with $x'=0$ is moving with velocity *v* wrt *S*:

$x=vt \Rightarrow 0 = Avt + Bt \Rightarrow B=-vA$

Thus Eq.(2) has the form:

5) $x`=A(x-vt)$

The origin of *O* with $x=0$ is moving with velocity *-v* wrt *S'*: with $x'=-vt'$

The article now says: Substitute $x'=-vt'$ in (3) and (5) we find: $D=A$

Now here my problem starts:

How does the writer arrive at this conclusion?. My step, which is wrong:

Use $x'= vt'$ in (5) and (3):

$A(x-vt) = v(Cx+Dt) \Rightarrow Ax -Avt = vCx + vDt$

Because x and t are independant? I conclude:
$D=A$ but also $A=vC$, which is wrong.

Thus in this case I also find $C=A/v$ which gives a wrong Lorenz transformation of:

\begin{equation*}
\begin{bmatrix} x` \\ t` \end{bmatrix} = 
\begin{pmatrix}
1   &  -v \\
1/v &   1 \\
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix} x \\ t \end{bmatrix}
\end{equation*}

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must remember the first part of this assumption:

"The origin of *O* with $x=0$ is moving with velocity *-v* wrt *S'*: with $x'=-vt'$"

You also forgot a minus sign.  $x'=-vt'$

Thus:
\begin{aligned}
Ax -Avt & = -vCx - vDt\qquad\vert\text{x has to be 0}\\
-Avt&=-vDt
\end{aligned}
And the desired result follows

Comment: Thanks very much!

Comment: Just a reminder, be sure to 'accept' the answer if it is what you're looking for.